# catkin_make fails

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I get an

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named workspaces Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
```

The same package compiles on another computer. The suggestions from [0] didn't work for me, any ideas?

```
PYTHONPATH: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages



$ dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg
    /.
    /usr
    /usr/bin
    /usr/bin/catkin_create_pkg
    /usr/share
    /usr/share/python-support
    /usr/share/python-support/python-catkin-pkg.public
    /usr/share/pyshared
    /usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg
    /usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg/package.py
    /usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg/packages.py
    /usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py
    /usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg/__init__.py
    /usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py
    /usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg-0.1.4.egg-info
    /usr/share/doc
    /usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg
    /usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/changelog.Debian.gz


$ python -c 'import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__file__)'
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/catkin_pkg/__init__.pyc
```

Many thanks!

[0] http://answers.ros.org/question/56873/problem-with-catkin_make/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61027/catkin_make-fails/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a common problem where you have `catkin_pkg` from pip located at `/usr/local/lib...` which is out-of-date and overriding the up-to-date `catkin_pkg` from apt. The answer in the referenced question should work for you, but here is another answer which describes the same problem and a similar solution, maybe it will work for you:

http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1